# Test if two sets share 3 elements with Java streams

Tags: java, set, java-stream

I need a Java stream operation to test if two sets have at least 3 common elements.

Here is my Java 7 code that works fine:

```
@Test
public void testContainement(){
    Set<Integer> setOne = IntStream.of(0,1,4,3)
                                   .boxed()
                                   .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

    Set<Integer> setTwo = IntStream.of(0,1,4,5)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

    Assertions.assertEquals(true,testSets(setOne,setTwo));

}

private boolean testSets( Set<Integer> setOne, Set<Integer> setTwo ) {
    int counter=0;
    for (int x: setOne){
        if (setTwo.contains(x))
            counter++;
    }
    return counter > 2;
}
```

How can we do that with Java stream operations?

Comment: by the way that is not your java-7 code for the `@Test` method actually :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use simply `Set.retainAll(Collection)` :

```
setOne.retainAll(setTwo);
boolean isMoreTwo = setOne.size() > 2
```

If you don't want to modify `setOne`, create a new instance of the Set :

```
Set<Integer> newSetOne = new HashSet<>(setOne)
newSetOne.retainAll(setTwo);
boolean isMoreTwo = newSetOne.size() > 2
```

---

Note that all ways actually shown to solve your need (in your question, my answer and that one of Naman) are not correct way to perform an assertion in an unit test.
An assertion should produce a useful error message if the assertion fails.
So that will really not help you since a boolean is true or false and that's all   :

```
Assertions.assertEquals(true,testSets(setOne,setTwo));
```

Besides, it should also be written rather like :

```
Assertions.assertTrue(testSets(setOne,setTwo));
```

To achieve your requirement, you should count the number of matching elements between the sets and stopping it as soon as you reach the desired target.

```
long nbMatchLimitedToThree = setOne.stream().filter(setTwo::contains).limit(3).count();
Assertions.assertEqual(3, nbMatchLimitedToThree, "At least 3 matches expected but actually only " +  nbMatchLimitedToThree +". setOne=" + setOne + ",setTwo=" + setTwo);
```

That is more performant and that is a correct way to write unit tests.

Comment: is this solution the best considering memory and time consumption. because i will have thousands calls to this methods. do you agree the other awnser is the best considering my requirements. Thanks for the help

Comment: I posted an update. The second part should give you the correct way to write this part in terms of performance and unit test.

Answer (score 6):

Use `Stream.count` as

```
private boolean testSets(Set<Integer> setOne, Set<Integer> setTwo) {
    return setOne.stream().filter(setTwo::contains).count() > 2;
}
```

or to add to it, avoiding to iterate through the complete set if more than two elements are found early, use `limit` as:

```
return setOne.stream().filter(setTwo::contains).limit(3).count() > 2;
```

Comment: You might want to put `limit(3)` after `filter` to prevent the stream from going over all the elements of `setOne` when not necessary.

Comment: @Slaw yup makes sense to short-circuit using limit. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

guava makes this very easy to read:

```
private boolean testSets( Set<Integer> setOne, Set<Integer> setTwo ) {
     return Sets.intersection(setOne, setTwo).size() > 2;
}
```